# Function call from template ends in infinite loop - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

I'm calling a function from template which makes an `async` call and displays the returned response in html. However, this call ends up in an infinite loop.

I've read the solution that we should use Change Detection strategy but that also doesn't help.

**sample.html :**

```
<div *ngFor = "let data of hugeData; let i = index">
 <span *ngIf="getData(i) | async as variable" [innerHTML] = "variable">
</div>
```

**sample.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
selector : 'sample',
templateUrl : './sample.html',
changeDetection : ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

**Function call in sample.component.ts:**

```
getData(i){
 return new Promise (function (resolve,reject){
  this.makeApiCall(i).subscribe(response=>{
  this.cd.detectChanges();
  resolve(response);
  })
 })
}
```

`makeApiCall(i)` is another function call that makes an API call and returns the response as an Observable.

In this case, it throws an error :
Cannot read property 'makeApiCall' of undefined.

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `this` is referencing the function that was passed in the `Promise` parameter, you probably want `this` to refer to the class

A simple solution would be to use the arrow function on `Promise`.

Ex:

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Henrique. This worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the type of your response:

```js
   
.subscribe((response: Datatype) => {...})
```

or you can try:

```js
public reloadNotifier: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
notifyForReload() {
        this.reloadNotifier.next();
    }

this.makeApiCall(i).reloadNotifier.subscribe(response ...
```

I had simular problems and one of it solved it each time. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Elke for your quick response:)  However, this code throws an error at reloadNotifier. Can you please explain a bit. And, I can't even use this.reloadNotifier in this line of code -```this.makeApiCall(i).reloadNotifier.subscribe(response...```

Comment: When it throws an error at reloadNotifier, this could be the reason you can't use it.